# Not able to execute the sql query variable in Snowflake UDF

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to create a snowflake UDF which allocates some workdays based on the max and min dates.

Can we execute the javascript UDF like procedure?. Appreciate your thoughts on this

Getting an error while executing the below code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UDF_OTD_ADDWORKDAYS ("STARTDATE" date,"WORKDAYS" float,"FACTORYID" varchar(2))
RETURNS date
LANGUAGE Javascript
AS
$$
function dd(input)
{

var D=STARTDATE;
var WORKDAYS_REM=WORKDAYS;
var source_min_table =     
     `SELECT MIN(DateID) FROM CALENDAR;` ;     
var min_day = snowflake.createStatement(
            {sqlText: source_min_table});
var source_min_day = min_day.execute();
var source_max_table =     
     `SELECT max(DateID) FROM CALENDAR;` ;     
var max_day = snowflake.createStatement(
            {sqlText: source_max_table});
var source_max_day = max_day.execute();

if(WORKDAYS > 0)
{
while ((WORKDAYS_REM > 0) && (D < source_max_day))
{
var D = DATEADD(day, 1, D);
var addr_temp = snowflake.createStatement( { sqlText: "SELECT WorkDay_Int FROM CALENDAR WHERE FactoryID = '''+FACTORYID+''' AND DateID = '''+D''';" } );
var Adder = addr_temp.execute();
let WORKDAYS_REM=(WORKDAYS_REM-Adder);
}
return D;
}

if(WORKDAYS < 0)
{
var WORKDAYS_REM = ABS(WORKDAYS_REM)
while((WORKDAYS_REM > 0) && (D > source_min_day))
{
var D = DATEADD(day,-1, D);
var addr_temp = snowflake.createStatement( { sqlText: "SELECT WorkDay_Int FROM CALENDAR WHERE FactoryID = '''+FACTORYID+''' AND DateID = '''+D+''';" } );
var Adder = addr_temp.execute();
let WORKDAYS_REM = (WORKDAYS_REM-Adder);
}
return D;
}
return D;
}
return dd();
$$
;
```

error :

**JavaScript execution error: Uncaught ReferenceError: snowflake is not defined in UDF_OTD_ADDWORKDAYS at 'var min_day = snowflake.createStatement(' position 14 stackstrace: dd line: 9 UDF_OTD_ADDWORKDAYS line: 44**

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript UDFs do not have the `snowflake` API object and they cannot run queries. What you could do if your `CALENDAR` table is small enough is send the whole table to your JavaScript function as a JSON. Here's an example using the Snowflake sample data:

```
select array_agg(object_construct(N.*)) as NATION_LIST from "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCH_SF1"."NATION" N;

create or replace function USE_JSON_SCALAR(V variant)
returns string
language javascript
strict immutable
as
$$
    return JSON.stringify(V[0].N_NAME);
$$;

select use_json_scalar(array_agg(object_construct(N.*))) as NATION_LIST from "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCH_SF1"."NATION" N;
```

If there are other tables (most of the time there will be), just join in the `CALENDAR` or in this case the `NATION` table somewhere and build the JSON as shown.

Comment: We are looping and adding workdays on a date column based on max dates..can this be possible by using above example ?.

Comment: We'd need to work through an example interactively. You can have your sales engineer contact me if you'd like to arrange a session to try working through the requirements.